# What spaces are considered not 'in Arkham'

Tags: arkham-horror

For the action "All Cthonians and Dholes in Arkham are returned to the cup," does this include the outskirts and sky spaces?

Edit: since these creatures cannot fly, this question is more about whether such monsters in the outskirts would be returned, i.e. whether they are considered "in Arkham". Short of finding some rules reference, I would think the fact that gate closing affects monsters from the outskirts would make it likely removing creates "in Arkham" implies the outskirts as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Arkham Horror FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/AHfaq.pdf):

> The Sky is considered part of Arkham (since it is on the Arkham board)

And

> A monster that is arriving in Arkham is moved to the Outskirts if its arrival would exceed the monster limit.

So the sky is considered part of Arkham. The outskirts are never considered part of arkham.

(Also, it is impossible for Cthonians and Dholes to get to the sky)

Comment: I'd like to revisit this question. I feel like the quoted text doesn't quite argue that the outskirts aren't part of Arkham and that a directive saying to remove all ___ from Arkham should likely include those in the outskirts. Did you find other supporting rule text to clarify this?

Comment: Other rules that reference amount of monsters in 'arkham',  such as the monster limit,  do NOT count the outskirts. I think it is quite clear

Comment: I see references to the outskirts separately from Arkham as well such as with gate closings ie "When a gate is closed, all monsters in Arkham, the Sky, and the Outskirts that have the same..."

Comment: The FAQ are pretty direct: Q: When a Mythos Card says all Chthonians and Dholes
in Arkham are returned to the cup, does the Outskirts
count as “in Arkham?” A: No. Q: If the number of monsters in Arkham is at the monster
limit, and a monster that is on an expansion board moves
to the Sky, what happens to that monster?
A: The monster is moved to the Outskirts. The Sky is considered
part of Arkham...